# HP Z420/620/820 SAS controller support

Tags: kernel, hp, sata

The HP Z420/620/820 series workstations have the Intel C602 chipset. They are coming up on ten years old, but E5-26xx v2 Xeons are still plenty of power and they use DDR3 dram, which is getting really cheap. They are no where near end of life.

The mainboard has two SATA 6Gbps ports, two SATA 1.5Gbps for optical drives, and there are four SAS/SATA 3Gbps ports. Starting with kernel 5.4.1 (I think) the needed drivers for the 3Gbps ports are no longer included. I've pinned the half dozen workstations I own at 5.4.0-58-generic or 5.4.0-70-generic.

My questions are:

1. Is there some really good reason this particular piece of hardware was dropped from support?
2. Is there a concise reference page for re-enabling support?
3. Assuming this is just an oversight, how does one request that the driver be restored?

My experience with Linux started with Redhat 3.03, so I've had to build some kernels over the years, but it's been ... twenty years? This seems like a real nuisance in 2021.

This is the relevant stuff from dmesg for both SATA and SAS.

[    2.837517] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xef44c000 port 0xef44c100 irq 44
[    2.837519] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xef44c000 port 0xef44c180 irq 44
[    3.151867] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    3.151912] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)

[    2.825923] isci: Intel(R) C600 SAS Controller Driver - version 1.2.0
[    2.833679] isci 0000:02:00.0: OEM SAS parameters (version: 1.1) loaded (platform)
[    4.117144] sas: phy-1:2 added to port-1:0, phy_mask:0x4 (500110ad00f80978)
[    4.117437] sas: DOING DISCOVERY on port 0, pid:447
[    4.117658] sas: Enter sas_scsi_recover_host busy: 0 failed: 0
[    4.117691] sas: ata7: end_device-1:0: dev error handler
[    4.312036] sas: --- Exit sas_scsi_recover_host: busy: 0 failed: 0 tries: 1
[    4.322683] sas: DONE DISCOVERY on port 0, pid:447, result:0
[    4.322764] sas: phy-1:3 added to port-1:1, phy_mask:0x8 (500110ad00f80979)
[    4.322977] sas: DOING DISCOVERY on port 1, pid:447
[    4.323021] sas: Enter sas_scsi_recover_host busy: 0 failed: 0
[    4.323076] sas: ata7: end_device-1:0: dev error handler
[    4.323100] sas: ata8: end_device-1:1: dev error handler
[    4.511723] sas: --- Exit sas_scsi_recover_host: busy: 0 failed: 0 tries: 1
[    4.522282] sas: DONE DISCOVERY on port 1, pid:447, result:0

Comment: Check kernel.org to see if the hardware was deliberately dropped. If not, test the hardware with a (pre-release) 21.04 LiveUSB. If the hardware was not dropped but is not recognized by the latest Ubuntu kernel (which is in 21.04), then it's a reversion -- file a bug report: `ubuntu-bug linux`. If you have time, try different LiveUSBs with different releases: A bit of bisection on your part to narrow which set of kernel commits created the problem will go a long way toward convincing the kernel developers that your bug is real and worth pursuing.

Comment: I have an HP Z420 that's E5-26xxv1 only, it's going to be passed on to one of our interns, so I have a test bed for this task. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Final solution on this was $20 for two port SATA cards from Amazon. Not a full replacement of the missing SAS ports, but works for machine I'm passing on and I don't have to fret about a non-technical user facing a machine that's misplaced its /home volume.